# wifi problem after connecting to wired connection in kubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, internet

A few days ago I installed Kubuntu 15.04 on my laptop. in first day I had no problem using WiFi at home but in my office I have no WiFi and I have to use a wired Ethernet cable to connect to the Internet and Kubuntu couldn't connect to wired connection!
I searched and found this solution: adding two line of following commands to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and my problem with wired connection solved!

but a new problem was born!
after this, my WiFi disconnects every time after a few minutes!
and when I remove that code it will be OK!

can anyone tell me how I can have WiFi and wired Internet together?

Comment: you want to connect both wifi and ethernet to internet at the same time?

Comment: @Ron No! I want to connect to both of them separately! but without adding and removing that two lines of commands every time I switch between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to edit /etc/network/interfaces.

When you connect to a wired network, just disable wireless in Network Manager. And wired network card will receive an ip address by dhcp.
It should work this way.