# Ubuntu 15.04 with two connections (WiFi & Wired) can't access internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 15.04

I got a Ubuntu 15.04 (upgraded from LTS) laptop and there is this ongoing bug that is pretty annoying.

I use it in WiFi when I'm around the office, and I use the wired connection when it's on my table, both are the same network connected to some central server (Cisco or something like that, I'm not sure).

**The issue is that:** everytime I boot-up the computer in my table in the morning, the WiFi is on (`Enable WiFi` is market on the drop-down menu at top) and it is also connected to the wire. And with both connections the computer refuses to connect to anything.

With that I have to everyday, when I boot the computer, disable WiFi to be able to use the network, and when I'm around the office I have to enable and disable as the day goes.

A few more data about the system:

- Dell XPS "ultrathin" running 15.04, Unity, default kernel.
- On 14.04 was working fine, after the upgrade to 15.04 it started happening.
- from `lspci` WiFi is: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
- Wired is an Apple USB adapter (there's none on the laptop). From `lsusb`: Apple, Inc. Ethernet Adapter [A1277]
- If both connected: no pages load, `ping www.google.com` unknow host.
- Everything works as expected if it's just one or just the other
- `ifconf`: (seems OK and other PCs in the office have no problem)

  - eth0: `inet addr:10.102.10.188  Bcast:10.102.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0`
  - wlan0: `inet addr:10.102.10.108  Bcast:10.102.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0`

I don't need to be connected to both at the same time, but 
I don't think that answer [wifi problem after connecting to wired connection in kubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620167/wifi-problem-after-connecting-to-wired-connection-in-kubuntu-15-04) is good enough. I believe Ubuntu should be able to automatically handle connection switch over to the preferred connection (wired)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1436330) which got fixed in the [network-manger-0.9.10.0-4ubuntu18](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/network-manager/0.9.10.0-4ubuntu18) which is in the ubuntu 15.10 repository. I was not successful to install the wily package on my vivid because of dependency issues. But maybe you can get it work.